# Windows Update detects one 32 bit update when I have 64 bit Office 2013 installed

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, microsoft-office-2013

I have MS Office 2013 Standard installed on Windows 10. Post installation I ran Windows Update to installed the latest updates.

All the updates installed except this one:

> Update for Microsoft Office 2013 (KB2965253) 32-Bit Edition - Error
>   0x80240017

I'm unsure why the 32 bit version is detected only for this update. Note that the 64 bit version of the same update is already installed.

Things I have tried:

1. Offline install by downloading the update: 64 bit version says it's already installed. 32 bit version says no affected products.
2. Googling fixes for "Error 0x80240017" - No results.

Why is Windows Update detecting one 32 bit update and how do I fix this error?

Comment: What do you mean by fix? 0x800240017 means update is not applicable (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/938205), so it was correctly not installed.

Comment: The fixes mentioned here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/windows-10-office-2013-update-fails-with-error/7e99c27f-b322-4e41-8bf9-62bd3d3f6a63 and here: http://www.fixerrs.com/2015/09/fix-error-0x80240017-Windows-8-81-10.html

Comment: The error makes sense. The 32 bit KB2965253 is not applicable. However, my Windows Update detects this update and tries to install it repeatedly

Comment: If you haven't, try running the update troubleshooter in Control panel. If it's being repeatedly offered the error is probably Microsoft's rather than anything you can do. Try hiding the update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3073930

Answer (score -3):

You installed a 32 bit driver for ODBC and/or Access files.

Look to see if a Visio Plug in was installed, or an Access catalog of drivers (AccessDatabaseEngine) These are usually 32 bit (on my systems anyhow) and I needed to UNINSTALL them first before I could install any 64 bit stuff. I needed them after the 64 bit Office install, and was able to re-install them after Office 64bit was installed/activated.

Comment: 32-bit driver on a 64-bit OS? I'm not sure that's even possible. But you forgot the "how do I fix this error?" anyway.

Comment: I am not saying you are wrong, but the OP brought a whole problem here and your answer must be a whole solution. For chiming in on anything else, we have a comment section.